# Multiple imputations with MICE and Latent Profile Analysis with tidyLPA

Tags: r, profile, imputation, r-mice

I am trying to do a multiple imputation with the mice package and later use those results to do a latent profile analysis with the tidyLPA package. However, I am running into coding problems and I am not sure if it can be solved. I have seen examples on the internet that after the imputation people fit linear / logistic models and using the pool function to pool the R squared estimate but not performing a Latent Profile Analysis.

Averaging the results won't be a good idea as I have read in numerous posts it won't take into account the variability among the imputed datasets.

The code gives me an error before conducting Latent Profile analysis which is the following:
Error in df[, select_vars, drop = FALSE] : incorrect number of dimensions

I am attaching a small example here to check if anyone is having a solution / suggestions.

Thank you in advance.

```
library("mice")
library("tidyLPA")

data <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4),
               var1 = c(1, 2, 5, 10, NA, 5, 23, NA, NA, 1),
               var2 = c(1, NA, NA, 1, NA, 0, 1, 3, 23, 4))

imputation <- mice(data, m = 5, 
               method = c("", "pmm", "pmm"),
               maxit = 20)

LPA <- with(imputation, estimate_profiles(imputation, n_profiles = 2, variances = "equal", 
                 covariances = "equal"))
```

Comment: I know it's been 1.5 months, but did you ever find a solution to this issue?

Comment: Hey, no I have not. And I am not sure if it is possible at all. There was another person that was having the same question as me here: https://groups.google.com/g/tidylpa/c/V-qmaS2MZi0

Comment: Thanks for letting me know! I posted about this on the tidyLPA Github, so if it is possible, they might be able to provide a good way of going about it: https://github.com/data-edu/tidyLPA/issues/186

Comment: Hey, thanks for letting me know as well :)